# jsp file to sort data retrieved from csv file

Tags: html, jsp, html-table, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file which has lastname and first name, i have a jsp file to to retrieve the data from CSV file. This is what I have done so far:

```
<body>
<%
String file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\file.csv";
String line;

int count = 0;
int i = 0;

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
%>
<table border=0>
<%
    while((line = dis.readLine())!=null) {
%>
<tr>
<% 
String[] str = line.split(",");
for(int j=0; j<str.length; j++) {
%>
<td>
<%          
    out.print(" " + str[j] + " ");
%>
</td>
<%
    }
%>
</tr>
<%
    //out.println("<br>");
    i++;
}
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But I need to sort the table based on last name, so what should I do in jsp file?

Comment: As an aside.... You might want to consider processing the file on the server side and not in the JSP; it's almost always better to carry out this logic in controllers and services on the back end.  Apologies if you already considered this.

Comment: Thanks Ray, but i am not using servlets here, just jsp file to retrieve from csv file and sort based on one of the columns in the jsp file only

Comment: Okay, understood.  That's fine for complete JSP-fronted applications, then.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to store first and last name into a [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and then can sort that List Using [Collection.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method and displaying that list straight away in your jsp.

BTW you should not do this thing inside scriplet tag ,instead you can do all this inside a servlet class.In place of hardcoding filepath you should use something like property files .